Маскировка своего ip с помощью nginx
мой сервер использует внешние сервисы(openai api), которые недоступны в моей стране, я хочу использовать прокси, чтобы скрыть свой ip от других сервисов, я перепробовал много вариантов, ни один не помог, пока я пытаюсь настроить nginx для этого, они везде пишут об этой настройке:
server{
listen 80;
server_name myIP;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
server{
listen proxyPort;
server_name _;
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic base64(login and password proxy)";
return 301 http://proxyIP;
}

можно ли скрыть свой ip с помощью nginx? если да, то что я делаю не так, если нет, то что мне следует использовать. p.s. Я не использую ничего, кроме nginx. Порт, который необходимо замаскировать, выделен для сервера websocket. Чтобы использовать мой прокси, вам нужно указать ip, порт, имя пользователя и пароль
Я пробовал настроить глобальный прокси в ubuntu, настроил 3proxy, настроил прокси через nginx

Если Вам нужно "спрятать" сервер за другим ip, proxy тут не поможет.
Необходимо купить самую дешёвую VPS с публичными IPv4/6-адресами, настроить на ней любой VPN между VPS и вашим сервером, затем на VPS настроить DNAT для нужных портов к локальному (внутри VPN) адресу вашего сервера. И для безопасности настроить firewall на VPS и сервере.
